# Calling from character to numeric data

Tags: r

I'm working on R and need to select randomly a set of parameters from the following sample:

```
params1 <- c(a=1, b=2, c=3)
params2 <- c(a=4, b=5, c=6)
params3 <- c(a=7, b=8, c=9)

selected<-sample(c(1,2,3),size=1, replace=TRUE, 
           prob=c(0.33,0.33,0.33))`
```

However when I use the following comand,

```
params<-paste("params",selected,sep="")
```

params is a character and not the numeric set of parameters that I need.

Maybe this question is very easy, but I am used to matlab language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this sort of thing in R is not to keep `param1`, `param2`, etc as isolated objects, but put them in a named list:

```
plist <- list(param1 = c(a=1, b=2, c=3),
              param2 = c(a=4, b=5, c=6),
              param3 = c(a=7, b=8, c=9))
```

And then you can select which one you want with numeric indexing, i.e. `plist[[selected]]`, or by name `plist[[paste0("param",selected)]]`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `get` to get the value of the object.

```
get(paste("params",selected,sep=""))
```

If there are multiple objects, use `mget` instead of `get` and it will return a `list` of values.

Or instead of `sample` on 1:3, we can directly apply on the 'params'

```
sample(mget(ls(pattern='^params\\d+')), size=1,
              prob=c(0.33,0.33,0.33))
```